# Pygame rect.contains collision not detecting

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am making a simple Breakout/Arkanoid game to learn pygame. I'm running into an issue where the rectangles of the paddle and the ball are not properly colliding. I also noticed that the ball doesn't collide with the bricks if I shoot the ball between two bricks, even when the ball sprite visually overlaps the bricks. This snippet if from the ball's `.update` method, which passes in the paddle and a list of bricks.

```
    new_pos = self.__calc_pos()

    # Check for collision with walls
    if not self.area.contains(new_pos):
        self.angle = -self.angle
        new_pos = self.__calc_pos()
    else:
        # Check for collision with paddle
        if paddle.rect.contains(new_pos):
            self.angle = -self.angle
            new_pos = self.__calc_pos()

        # Check for collision with bricks
        for brick in bricks:
            if brick.rect.contains(new_pos):
                self.angle = -self.angle
                new_pos = self.__calc_pos()
                brick.kill()
                bricks.remove(brick)

    self.rect = new_pos
```

The `.__calc_pos` method:

```
def __calc_pos(self):
    new_x = int(math.cos(math.radians(self.angle))) * self.speed
    new_y = -int(math.sin(math.radians(self.angle))) * self.speed
    return self.rect.move(new_x, new_y)
```

Comment: What does your `.contains()` method look like?

Comment: `contains` checks if one rect if fully inside another rect - and it doesn't true if one object only partially touch other object. Use `colliderect()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[contains()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.contains) checks if one rect if fully inside another rect - and it doesn't true if one object only partially touch other object. Use [colliderect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

> **contains()**
>      test if one rectangle is inside another
>       contains(Rect) -> bool
>      Returns true when the argument is **completely inside** the Rect.

-

> **colliderect()**
>      test if two rectangles overlap
>      colliderect(Rect) -> bool
>      Returns true if **any portion of either rectangle overlap** (except the top+bottom or left+right edges).

Comment: Ha, this was it. My misunderstanding of the method. Thanks!